# Magento 2 creating an auto invoice at the time of shipment getting an error on the order view page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-enterprise, invoice, code-generation

Magento 2 creating an auto invoice at the time of shipment getting an error on the order view page.

After successfully creating an invoice when the page redirected to order view getting an error mentioned on the image.

Email one is fine but adminhtml/session I am not getting anyone?

thanks in advance.

I am creating an invoice programmatically from the observer using

```
event --> "sales_order_shipment_save_after"
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you debug this with xdebug to pin-point the problem. since you haven't provided any piece of code, it's hard to tell what's the problem just by looking at an error message.

Comment: @DianaBotean thanks for the suggestion let me check.